# Can I configure i3 to wrap from my rightmost workspace to my leftmost when I press <mod>+right?

Tags: i3, window-management

Let's say I have 3 monitors arranged like this:

```
[] [] []
```

Is there a way to configure i3 so that if I press `<mod>+right` when I'm on the rightmost window on the rightmost monitor, it moves focus to the leftmost window on the leftmost monitor? This would be faster than repeatedly pressing `<mod>+left`.